# How to configure an Ubuntu server so that all traffic goes through a VPN?

Tags: server, vpn

**This question is Not about how to set up VPN on an Ubuntu server.**

Edited: I think what I'm looking for is the way to set up a PPTP VPN client on my Ubuntu server by command line.

I have an Ubuntu server running and connected to the internet. I also have a VPN service (PPTP) running on another Linux machine. Now all I want to do is configure this Ubuntu server so that all the internet traffic it generates goes through the VPN.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this below link

you need to install pptpd

http://kamleshgosavi.blogspot.in/2011/01/vpn-server-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: In my question I made it very clear (the first line) I am not asking how to set up a VPN server on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Change the default route on your server to point to the machine which has the PPTP client running.  In /etc/network/interfaces, change the `gateway` line to point to the PPTP client machine, then restart the machine (or just restart the interface, if you're feeling frisky.  or just change the default route manually with the `route` command, if you're feeling *extra* frisky).

You'll also need to make certain that the machine with the PPTP tunnel up is willing to act as a gateway for traffic - this last can be done precisely with iptables, or it can be done more simply with `sysctl`.  To do it the simple way - enable acting as a gateway for any traffic it knows a route for - uncomment the net.ipv4.forward line in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and reread it:

```
sudo sed -i s/\#net\.ipv4\.ip_forward/net\.ipv4\.ip_forward/ /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

Hope this helps.